# Can't locate Ansible installed using pip on Mac

Tags: macos, ansible, macos-catalina

Installed Ansible on Mac using following command as documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#from-pip):

```
pip install --user ansible
```

However, can't find Ansible with version command:

```
~ $ ansible --version
-bash: ansible: command not found
```

any clues?

Answer (score 3):

For modern macOS/OSX, you need to find your `~/Library/Python/$version/bin` directory and add it to your environment PATH  `export PATH=[YOUR ansible installed location]`. This will help you locate the one where ansible got installed.

Comment: Added "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin" inside "/etc/paths" but no luck. Still get message "ansible: command not found" for "ansible --version"

Answer (score 0):

try here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
```

**change python3.9 with your python version...**

otherwise in terminal write:

```
where ansible
```

probably return a path similar to this:

```
/usr/local/bin/ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the `--user` option.

This causes them to be installed inside the user base’s binary directory, which may, or may not already be present in your shell’s `PATH`. (Starting in version 10, pip displays a warning when installing any scripts to a directory outside `PATH`.)

If the scripts are not available in your shell after installation, you'll need to add the directory to your `PATH`:

```bash
export PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
```

On Linux and macOS you can find the user base binary directory by running
`python -m site --user-base` and adding bin to the end